# ORM Property Multiple Relationships

Tags: orm, coldfusion, properties, components, relationship

Im defining my cfc's and would like to know how you can define multiple relationships on the same column? For instance in a database which stores pets, their owners and their vet records:
pet table would have a id which is listed in both the owners and the vet records tables (whether via linked tables or not doesn't matter), pets can have multiple owners, owners can have multiple pets, pets can have multiple vet records, a vet record can only have one pet.

The pet id would need to link to both the vet records CFC and the Owners CFC, how do you define this in the component property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realise that you add an entire property in for each relationship. I thought you added the relationship to the property representing the column with the relationship.

So the answer is simply add a new property for each relationship